# Setting window name causes null reference wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, window

When I set `Window.name = "window name here"`, I get a null reference exception on `Window.Show()`. Please see code:

```
                MyWindow = new Window {
                                      ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize,
                                      WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None,
                                      // set content and other properties here...
                                      WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen,
                                      Name = "Customize Toolbar" // Omitting this allows code to run, leaving this causes null reference exception
                                  };
```

Why does setting the name cause this issue? setting the `Title` does not cause a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the space from your Name. Use something like

```
Name = "CustomizeToolbar"
```

Comment: Thanks that resolves the issue. I didn't know that the Name was the identifying property, I assumed it did what Title does. Now I know! Thanks.

Comment: I will in ten minutes, when it allows me to.